# Selenium - how to assert that field is equal to 0

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create an assert which will compare a field (IWebElement) with specific value.

My Webelement, which holds base amount/text: '0.00€'

```
var TotalField = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='total-container']//*[text()='0.00€']"));
```

I'm doing test which bases on payment process, I'm adding specific product to the basket and then after doing the payment I need to compare whether that field: "TotalField" is still, after payment process equals to base value (0.00€). If it's not then assert should show it.

I'm wondering how it can be done & what assert type should be taken:
Assert.AreEqual? Assert.IsTrue?

Code:

```
    <div class="total-container" style="width: 100%; display: flex; height: 74px; font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold;">
<div>TOTAL:</div>
<div>0.00€</div></div>
```

Comment: can share the html code for the above element?

Comment: Already there, as you can see at the beginning of the process there is a value "0.00" and my goal is to check whether after payment this value is still the same. @Murthi

Comment: Use a way to find the element WITHOUT the text()=... Then use getText() to get the text out. Do this before, store the value in a variable, then after and compare to the variable. Any assert will do. Trying to find the elements like this,, with the text()=... will likely result in ugly Exceptions because they may or may not be present

Comment: Thank you @Chai and Murthi :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try -

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("url here");
        String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='total-container']//div[2]")).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(text, "0.00€");
    }

}
```

Comment: In c# I don't have getText option, instead of that I'm using .Text. Then assert: Assert.AreEqual(text, 0.00€). No compile error occurs but the outcome is always success, even thought "Total Value" is different then 0.00

Comment: Did you output the value that comes after you use `.Text` ? If you are getting the value, then Assert should be pretty fine I believe.